# .htaccess mod_rewrite - reserved folder names

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm rewriting a url to a users profile with mod_rewrite like this: domain.com/users/JohnSmith.

I was thinking maybe it would be neater to skip the users folder and simply put it like: domain.com/JohnSmith.

My question: How do I do this and keep my system and site folders? If I look for domain.com/browsersupport, the profile.php page will check the name and look for it in a database, and since no user has that name, no page will be shown.

I know it can be fixed with some if statements in the PHP-code. Also, the folders name need to be reserved so users can't register those names. But for the profile look up - is there a neater way? Maybe to exclude the system folders in the .htaccess file so profile.php won't go look for that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is where these 2 conditions come into play:

```
  # if the request does NOT map to a file
  RewriteCOnd %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  # and the request does NOT map to a directory
  RewriteCOnd %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # only THEN use this rewriterule
  RewriteRulle ....etc...
```

If you have *both* 'dynamic' pages, and dynamic users, the RewriteRule should end in a process that checks whether a page by that name exists, and only if it doesn't, serve the user page.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule #insert user rewrite rule here
```

This will only apply the rewrite rule if a folder or file by that given name does not exist (your question seems to imply that `browsersupport` and the like do exist in the document root like that).

Yes you will have to be diligent about letting users know that they can't register certain names like that.  If they do, they won't be able to access their username by that route.

I've done this, but I have a self-imposed rule that is probably not for everyone but works for me: usernames must be 5 characters at least, and controllers are 4 or less.